# Collision Detection between two images in Java

Tags: java, collision-detection

I have two characters displayed in a game I am writing, the player and the enemy. defined as such:

```
public void player(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(plimg, x, y, this);
}

public void enemy(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(enemy, 200, 200, this);
}
```

Then called with:

```
player(g);
enemy(g);
```

I am able to move player() around with the keyboard, but I am at a loss when trying to detect a collision between the two. A lot of people have said to use Rectangles, but being a beginner I cannot see how I would link this into my existing code. Can anyone offer some advice for me?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are not using good OO design for your player and enemies. Create two classes:

```
public class Player
{
    int X;
    int Y;
    int Width;
    int Height;

    // Getters and Setters
}

public class Enemy
{
    int X;
    int Y;
    int Width;
    int Height;

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

Your Player should have X,Y,Width,and Height variables.

Your enemies should as well.

In your game loop, do something like this (C#):

```
foreach (Enemy e in EnemyCollection)
{
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(e.X,e.Y,e.Width,e.Height);
    Rectangle p = new Rectangle(player.X,player.Y,player.Width,player.Height);

    // Assuming there is an intersect method, otherwise just handcompare the values
    if (r.Intersects(p))
    {
       // A Collision!
       // we know which enemy (e), so we can call e.DoCollision();
       e.DoCollision();
    }
}
```

To speed things up, don't bother checking if the enemies coords are offscreen.

Comment: Correct. My OO skills are dreadful, and the majority of my game exists in one file. Your method works, but I've got a lot of work in trying to separate this one file into its respective classes.

Comment: Oh, for... put the Rectangles in the Player and Enemy classes.  `r = e.getRectangle();` is faster and easier on the eyes.

Answer (score 5):

First, use the bounding boxes as described by [Jonathan Holland](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335600/collision-detection-between-two-images-in-java#335632) to find if you may have a collision.

From the (multi-color) sprites, create black and white versions. You probably already have these if your sprites are transparent (i.e. there are places which are inside the bounding box but you can still see the background). These are "masks".

Use `Image.getRGB()` on the mask to get at the pixels. For each pixel which isn't transparent, set a bit in an integer array (`playerArray` and `enemyArray` below). The size of the array is `height` if `width <= 32` pixels, `(width+31)/32*height` otherwise. The code below is for `width <= 32`.

If you have a collision of the bounding boxes, do this:

```
// Find the first line where the two sprites might overlap
int linePlayer, lineEnemy;
if (player.y <= enemy.y) {
    linePlayer = enemy.y - player.y;
    lineEnemy = 0;
} else {
    linePlayer = 0;
    lineEnemy = player.y - enemy.y;
}
int line = Math.max(linePlayer, lineEnemy);

// Get the shift between the two
x = player.x - enemy.x;
int maxLines = Math.max(player.height, enemy.height);
for ( line < maxLines; line ++) {
    // if width > 32, then you need a second loop here
    long playerMask = playerArray[linePlayer];
    long enemyMask = enemyArray[lineEnemy];
    // Reproduce the shift between the two sprites
    if (x < 0) playerMask << (-x);
    else enemyMask << x;
    // If the two masks have common bits, binary AND will return != 0
    if ((playerMask & enemyMask) != 0) {
        // Contact!
    }

}
```

Links: [JGame](http://www.13thmonkey.org/~boris/jgame/), [Framework for Small Java Games](http://vredungmand.dk/programming/sjg/)

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to have the collision check code inside the painting code.  The painting needs to be fast.  Collision can go in the game loop.  Therefore you need an internal representation of the objects independent of their sprites.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the main class from my collision detection program.
You can see it run at: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JIXhCvXgjsQ

```
/**
 *
 * @author Tyler Griffin
 */
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;


public class collision extends JFrame implements KeyListener, MouseMotionListener, MouseListener
{
    ArrayList everything=new ArrayList<tile>();

    int time=0, x, y, width, height, up=0, down=0, left=0, right=0, mouse1=0, mouse2=0;
    int mouseX, mouseY;

    GraphicsEnvironment environment = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice screen = environment.getDefaultScreenDevice();
    DisplayMode displayMode = screen.getDisplayMode();

    //private BufferStrategy strategy;

    JLayeredPane pane = new JLayeredPane();

     tile Tile;
     circle Circle;
     rectangle Rectangle;

         textPane text;

    public collision()
    {
        setUndecorated(screen.isFullScreenSupported());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        setLayout(null);
        setResizable(false);
        screen.setFullScreenWindow(this);


        width=displayMode.getWidth();
        height=displayMode.getHeight();


          Circle=new circle(-(int)Math.round((double)height/7*2),-(int)Math.round((double)height/7*2),(int)Math.round((double)height/7*.85),this);
          Rectangle=new rectangle(-(int)Math.round((double)height/7*1.5),-(int)Math.round((double)height/7*1.5),(int)Math.round((double)height/7*1.5),(int)Math.round((double)height/7*1.5),this);
          Tile=Circle;
          Tile.move(mouseX-Tile.width/2, mouseY-Tile.height/2);
                  text=new textPane(0,0,width,height,this);

          everything.add(new circle((int)Math.round((double)width/100*75),(int)Math.round((double)height/100*15),(int)Math.round((double)width/100*10),this));
                  everything.add(new rectangle((int)Math.round((double)width/100*70),(int)Math.round((double)height/100*60),(int)Math.round((double)width/100*20),(int)Math.round((double)height/100*20),this));
                  //everything.add(new line(750,250,750,750,this));
                  /*everything.add(new line(width/700*419,height/700*68,width/700*495,height/700*345,this));
                  everything.add(new line(width/700*495,height/700*345,width/700*749,height/700*350,this));
                  everything.add(new line(width/700*749,height/700*350,width/700*549,height/700*519,this));
                  everything.add(new line(width/700*549,height/700*519,width/700*624,height/700*800,this));
                  everything.add(new line(width/700*624,height/700*800,width/700*419,height/700*638,this));
                  everything.add(new line(width/700*419,height/700*638,width/700*203,height/700*800,this));
                  everything.add(new line(width/700*203,height/700*800,width/700*279,height/700*519,this));
                  everything.add(new line(width/700*279,height/700*519,width/700*76,height/700*350,this));
                  everything.add(new line(width/700*76,height/700*350,width/700*333,height/700*345,this));
                  everything.add(new line(width/700*333,height/700*345,width/700*419,height/700*68,this));

                  everything.add(new line(width/950*419,height/700*68,width/950*624,height/700*800,this));
                  everything.add(new line(width/950*419,height/700*68,width/950*203,height/700*800,this));
                  everything.add(new line(width/950*76,height/700*350,width/950*624,height/700*800,this));
                  everything.add(new line(width/950*203,height/700*800,width/950*749,height/700*350,this));
                  everything.add(new rectangle(width/950*76,height/700*350,width/950*673,1,this));*/

                  everything.add(new line((int)Math.round((double)width/1350*419),(int)Math.round((double)height/1000*68),(int)Math.round((double)width/1350*624),(int)Math.round((double)height/1000*800),this));
                  everything.add(new line((int)Math.round((double)width/1350*419),(int)Math.round((double)height/1000*68),(int)Math.round((double)width/1350*203),(int)Math.round((double)height/1000*800),this));
                  everything.add(new line((int)Math.round((double)width/1350*76),(int)Math.round((double)height/1000*350),(int)Math.round((double)width/1350*624),(int)Math.round((double)height/1000*800),this));
                  everything.add(new line((int)Math.round((double)width/1350*203),(int)Math.round((double)height/1000*800),(int)Math.round((double)width/1350*749),(int)Math.round((double)height/1000*350),this));
                  everything.add(new rectangle((int)Math.round((double)width/1350*76),(int)Math.round((double)height/1000*350),(int)Math.round((double)width/1350*673),1,this));


        addKeyListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
    {
        Object source=e.getSource();

        int released=e.getKeyCode();

        if (released==KeyEvent.VK_A){left=0;}
        if (released==KeyEvent.VK_W){up=0;}
        if (released==KeyEvent.VK_D){right=0;}
        if (released==KeyEvent.VK_S){down=0;}
    }//end keyReleased


    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        Object source=e.getSource();

        int pressed=e.getKeyCode();

        if (pressed==KeyEvent.VK_A){left=1;}
        if (pressed==KeyEvent.VK_W){up=1;}
        if (pressed==KeyEvent.VK_D){right=1;}
        if (pressed==KeyEvent.VK_S){down=1;}

        if (pressed==KeyEvent.VK_PAUSE&&pressed==KeyEvent.VK_P)
        {
            //if (paused==0){paused=1;}
            //else paused=0;
        }
    }//end keyPressed

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){}

//***********************************************************************************************

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
    {
        mouseX=(e.getX());
        mouseY=(e.getY());

          //run();
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
    {
        mouseX=(e.getX());
        mouseY=(e.getY());

          //run();
    }

//***********************************************************************************************

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getX()==0 && e.getY()==0){System.exit(0);}

    mouseX=(e.getX()+x);
        mouseY=(e.getY()+y);

        if(Tile instanceof circle)
        {
                Circle.move(0-Circle.width, 0-Circle.height);
                Circle.setBounds(Circle.x, Circle.y, Circle.width, Circle.height);
                Tile=Rectangle;
        }
        else
        {
                Rectangle.move(0-Rectangle.width, 0-Rectangle.height);
                Rectangle.setBounds(Rectangle.x, Rectangle.y, Rectangle.width, Rectangle.height);
                Tile=Circle;
        }

        Tile.move(mouseX-Tile.width/2, mouseY-Tile.height/2);
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {
         //run();
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){}

//***********************************************************************************************

    public void run()//run collision detection
    {
        while (this == this)
        {
            Tile.move(Tile.x + ((mouseX - (Tile.x + (Tile.width / 2))) / 10), Tile.y + ((mouseY - (Tile.y + (Tile.height / 2))) / 10));
            //Tile.move((mouseX - Tile.width / 2), mouseY - (Tile.height / 2));

            for (int i = 0; i < everything.size(); i++)
            {
                tile Temp = (tile) everything.get(i);

                if (Temp.x < (Tile.x + Tile.width) && (Temp.x + Temp.width) > Tile.x && Temp.y < (Tile.y + Tile.height) && (Temp.y + Temp.height) > Tile.y)//rectangles collided
                {
                    if (Temp instanceof rectangle)
                    {
                        if (Tile instanceof rectangle){rectangleRectangle(Temp);}
                        else {circleRectangle(Temp);}//Tile instanceof circle
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (Temp instanceof circle)
                        {
                            if (Tile instanceof rectangle) {rectangleCircle(Temp);}
                            else {circleCircle(Temp);}
                        }
                        else//line
                        {
                            if (Tile instanceof rectangle){rectangleLine(Temp);}
                            else{circleLine(Temp);}
                        }
                    }
                }//end if
            }//end for

            try {Thread.sleep(16L);}
            catch (Exception e) {}

            Tile.setBounds(Tile.x, Tile.y, Tile.width, Tile.height);
            //Rectangle.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
            //Circle.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
            repaint();

            text.out=" ";
        }//end while loop
    }//end run

//***************************************special collision detection/handling functions************************************************

    void rectangleRectangle(tile Temp)
    {
        int lapTop, lapBot, lapLeft, lapRight, small, scootX=0, scootY=0;

        lapTop=(Temp.y+Temp.height)-Tile.y;
        lapBot=(Tile.y+Tile.height)-Temp.y;
        lapLeft=(Temp.x+Temp.width)-Tile.x;
        lapRight=(Tile.x+Tile.width)-Temp.x;

        small=999999999;

        if (lapTop<small){small=lapTop; scootX=0; scootY=lapTop;}
        if (lapBot<small){small=lapBot; scootX=0; scootY=lapBot*-1;}
                if (lapLeft<small){small=lapLeft; scootX=lapLeft; scootY=0;}
                if (lapRight<small){small=lapRight; scootX=lapRight*-1; scootY=0;}

        Tile.move(Tile.x+scootX, Tile.y+scootY);text.out="collision detected!";
    }



    void circleRectangle(tile Temp)
    {
        if((Tile.x+Tile.width/2<=Temp.x+Temp.width && Tile.x+Tile.width/2>=Temp.x)||(Tile.y+Tile.height/2>=Temp.y && Tile.y+Tile.height/2<=Temp.y+Temp.height))
        {
            rectangleRectangle(Temp);
        }
        else//push from nearest corner
        {
            int x,y;
            if(Tile.x+Tile.width/2>Temp.x+Temp.width && Tile.y+Tile.height/2<Temp.y){x=Temp.x+Temp.width; y=Temp.y;}
            else if(Tile.x+Tile.width/2<Temp.x && Tile.y+Tile.height/2<Temp.y){x=Temp.x; y=Temp.y;}
            else if(Tile.x+Tile.width/2>Temp.x+Temp.width && Tile.y+Tile.height/2>Temp.y+Temp.height){x=Temp.x+Temp.width; y=Temp.y+Temp.height;}
            else {x=Temp.x; y=Temp.y+Temp.height;}

            double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Tile.x+(Tile.width/2) - x, 2) + Math.pow(Tile.y+(Tile.height/2) - y, 2));

            if((int)Math.round(distance)<Tile.height/2)
            {
                             double normY = ((Tile.y+(Tile.height/2) - y) / distance);
                             double normX = ((Tile.x+(Tile.width/2) - x) / distance);

                            Tile.move(x-Tile.width/2+(int)Math.round(normX*((Tile.width/2))) , y-Tile.height/2+(int)Math.round(normY*((Tile.height/2))));text.out="collision detected!";
            }
        }
    }



    void rectangleCircle(tile Temp)
    {
        if((Temp.x+Temp.width/2<=Tile.x+Tile.width && Temp.x+Temp.width/2>=Tile.x)||(Temp.y+Temp.height/2>=Tile.y && Temp.y+Temp.height/2<=Tile.y+Tile.height))
        {
            rectangleRectangle(Temp);
        }
        else//push from nearest corner
        {
            int x,y;
            if(Temp.x+Temp.width/2>Tile.x+Tile.width && Temp.y+Temp.height/2<Tile.y){x=Tile.x+Tile.width; y=Tile.y;}
            else if(Temp.x+Temp.width/2<Tile.x && Temp.y+Temp.height/2<Tile.y){x=Tile.x; y=Tile.y;}
            else if(Temp.x+Temp.width/2>Tile.x+Tile.width && Temp.y+Temp.height/2>Tile.y+Tile.height){x=Tile.x+Tile.width; y=Tile.y+Tile.height;}
            else {x=Tile.x; y=Tile.y+Tile.height;}

            double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Temp.x+(Temp.width/2) - x, 2) + Math.pow(Temp.y+(Temp.height/2) - y, 2));

            if((int)Math.round(distance)<Temp.height/2)
            {
             double normY = ((Temp.y+(Temp.height/2) - y) / distance);
             double normX = ((Temp.x+(Temp.width/2) - x) / distance);

             if(Temp.x+Temp.width/2>Tile.x+Tile.width && Temp.y+Temp.height/2<Tile.y){Tile.move((Temp.x+Temp.width/2)-(int)Math.round(normX*((Temp.width/2)))-Tile.width,(Temp.y+Temp.height/2)-(int)Math.round(normY*((Temp.height/2))));text.out="collision detected!";}
                else if(Temp.x+Temp.width/2<Tile.x && Temp.y+Temp.height/2<Tile.y){Tile.move((Temp.x+Temp.width/2)-(int)Math.round(normX*((Temp.width/2))),(Temp.y+Temp.height/2)-(int)Math.round(normY*((Temp.height/2))));text.out="collision detected!";}
                else if(Temp.x+Temp.width/2>Tile.x+Tile.width && Temp.y+Temp.height/2>Tile.y+Tile.height){Tile.move((Temp.x+Temp.width/2)-(int)Math.round(normX*((Temp.width/2)))-Tile.width,(Temp.y+Temp.height/2)-(int)Math.round(normY*((Temp.height/2)))-Tile.height);text.out="collision detected!";}
                else {Tile.move((Temp.x+Temp.width/2)-(int)Math.round(normX*((Temp.width/2))),(Temp.y+Temp.height/2)-(int)Math.round(normY*((Temp.height/2)))-Tile.height);text.out="collision detected!";}
            }
        }
    }




    void circleCircle(tile Temp)
    {
        double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((Tile.x+(Tile.width/2)) - (Temp.x+(Temp.width/2)),2) + Math.pow((Tile.y+(Tile.height/2)) - (Temp.y+(Temp.height/2)), 2));

        if((int)distance<(Tile.width/2+Temp.width/2))
        {
                        double normX = ((Tile.x+(Tile.width/2)) - (Temp.x+(Temp.width/2))) / distance;
                        double normY = ((Tile.y+(Tile.height/2)) - (Temp.y+(Temp.height/2))) / distance;

            Tile.move((Temp.x+(Temp.width/2))+(int)Math.round(normX*(Tile.width/2+Temp.width/2))-(Tile.width/2) , (Temp.y+(Temp.height/2))+(int)Math.round(normY*(Tile.height/2+Temp.height/2))-(Tile.height/2));text.out="collision detected!";
        }
    }



    void circleLine(tile Temp)
    {
            line Line=(line)Temp;

            if (Line.x1 < (Tile.x + Tile.width) && (Line.x1) > Tile.x && Line.y1 < (Tile.y + Tile.height) && Line.y1 > Tile.y)//circle may be hitting one of the end points
            {
                rectangle rec=new rectangle(Line.x1, Line.y1, 1, 1, this);
                circleRectangle(rec);
                remove(rec);
            }

            if (Line.x2 < (Tile.x + Tile.width) && (Line.x2) > Tile.x && Line.y2 < (Tile.y + Tile.height) && Line.y2 > Tile.y)//circle may be hitting one of the end points
            {
                rectangle rec=new rectangle(Line.x2, Line.y2, 1, 1, this);
                circleRectangle(rec);
                remove(rec);
            }


            int x1=0, y1=0, x2=Tile.x+(Tile.width/2), y2=Tile.y+(Tile.height/2);

            x1=Tile.x+(Tile.width/2)-Line.height;//(int)Math.round(Line.xNorm*1000);
            x2=Tile.x+(Tile.width/2)+Line.height;
            if(Line.posSlope)
            {
                y1=Tile.y+(Tile.height/2)-Line.width;
                y2=Tile.y+(Tile.height/2)+Line.width;
            }
            else
            {
                y1=Tile.y+(Tile.height/2)+Line.width;
                y2=Tile.y+(Tile.height/2)-Line.width;
            }

            Point point=intersection((double)x1,(double)y1,(double)x2,(double)y2,(double)Line.x1,(double)Line.y1,(double)Line.x2,(double)Line.y2);//find intersection

            if (point.x < (Line.x + Line.width) && point.x > Line.x && point.y < (Line.y + Line.height) && point.y > Line.y)//line intersects within line segment
            {
                //if(point!=null){System.out.println(point.x+","+point.y);}
                double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((Tile.x+(Tile.width/2)) - point.x,2) + Math.pow((Tile.y+(Tile.width/2)) - point.y, 2));

                if((int)distance<Tile.width/2)
                {
                    //System.out.println("hit");
                    double normX = ((Tile.x+(Tile.width/2)) - point.x) / distance;
                    double normY = ((Tile.y+(Tile.height/2)) - point.y) / distance;

                    Tile.move((point.x)+(int)Math.round(normX*(Tile.width/2))-(Tile.width/2) , (point.y)+(int)Math.round(normY*(Tile.height/2))-(Tile.height/2));text.out="collision detected!";
                    //System.out.println(point.x+","+point.y);
                }
            }

            //new bullet(this, (int)Math.round(tryX), (int)Math.round(tryY));
    }

        void rectangleLine(tile Temp)
    {
            line Line=(line)Temp;
            if(new Line2D.Double(Line.x1,Line.y1,Line.x2,Line.y2).intersects(new Rectangle(Tile.x,Tile.y,Tile.width,Tile.height)))
            {
                if (Line.x1 < (Tile.x + Tile.width) && (Line.x1) > Tile.x && Line.y1 < (Tile.y + Tile.height) && Line.y1 > Tile.y)//circle may be hitting one of the end points
                {
                    rectangle rec=new rectangle(Line.x1, Line.y1, 1, 1, this);
                    rectangleRectangle(rec);
                    remove(rec);
                }

                if (Line.x2 < (Tile.x + Tile.width) && (Line.x2) > Tile.x && Line.y2 < (Tile.y + Tile.height) && Line.y2 > Tile.y)//circle may be hitting one of the end points
                {
                    rectangle rec=new rectangle(Line.x2, Line.y2, 1, 1, this);
                    rectangleRectangle(rec);
                    remove(rec);
                }

                if(Line.posSlope)//positive sloped line
                {
                    //first we'll do the top left corner
                    int x1=Tile.x-Line.height;
                    int x2=Tile.x+Line.height;
                    int y1=Tile.y-Line.width;
                    int y2=Tile.y+Line.width;
                    Point topPoint=new Point(-99,-99), botPoint=new Point(-99,-99);
                    double topDistance=0, botDistance=0;

                    topPoint=intersection((double)x1,(double)y1,(double)x2,(double)y2,(double)Line.x1,(double)Line.y1,(double)Line.x2,(double)Line.y2);//find intersection

                    topDistance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Tile.x - topPoint.x,2) + Math.pow(Tile.y - topPoint.y, 2));

                    //new let's do the bottom right corner
                    x1=Tile.x+Tile.width-Line.height;
                    x2=Tile.x+Tile.width+Line.height;
                    y1=Tile.y+Tile.height-Line.width;
                    y2=Tile.y+Tile.height+Line.width;

                    botPoint=intersection((double)x1,(double)y1,(double)x2,(double)y2,(double)Line.x1,(double)Line.y1,(double)Line.x2,(double)Line.y2);//find intersection

                    botDistance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((Tile.x+Tile.width) - botPoint.x,2) + Math.pow((Tile.y+Tile.height) - botPoint.y, 2));


                    if(topDistance<botDistance)
                    {
                        if(new Rectangle(Tile.x,Tile.y,Tile.width,Tile.height).contains(topPoint) && new Rectangle(Line.x,Line.y,Line.width,Line.height).contains(topPoint))
                        {
                            Tile.move(topPoint.x,topPoint.y);text.out="collision detected!";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(new Rectangle(Tile.x,Tile.y,Tile.width,Tile.height).contains(botPoint) && new Rectangle(Line.x,Line.y,Line.width,Line.height).contains(botPoint))
                        {
                            Tile.move(botPoint.x-Tile.width,botPoint.y-Tile.height);text.out="collision detected!";
                        }
                    }
                }
                else//negative sloped lne
                {
                    //first we'll do the top right corner
                    int x1=Tile.x+Tile.width-Line.height;
                    int x2=Tile.x+Tile.width+Line.height;
                    int y1=Tile.y+Line.width;
                    int y2=Tile.y-Line.width;
                    Point topPoint=new Point(-99,-99), botPoint=new Point(-99,-99);
                    double topDistance=0, botDistance=0;

                    topPoint=intersection((double)x1,(double)y1,(double)x2,(double)y2,(double)Line.x1,(double)Line.y1,(double)Line.x2,(double)Line.y2);//find intersection

                    topDistance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Tile.x + Tile.width - topPoint.x,2) + Math.pow(Tile.y - topPoint.y, 2));

                    //new let's do the bottom left corner
                    x1=Tile.x-Line.height;
                    x2=Tile.x+Line.height;
                    y1=Tile.y+Tile.height+Line.width;
                    y2=Tile.y+Tile.height-Line.width;

                    botPoint=intersection((double)x1,(double)y1,(double)x2,(double)y2,(double)Line.x1,(double)Line.y1,(double)Line.x2,(double)Line.y2);//find intersection

                    botDistance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Tile.x - botPoint.x,2) + Math.pow((Tile.y+Tile.height) - botPoint.y, 2));


                    if(topDistance<botDistance)
                    {
                        if(new Rectangle(Tile.x,Tile.y,Tile.width,Tile.height).contains(topPoint) && new Rectangle(Line.x,Line.y,Line.width,Line.height).contains(topPoint))
                        {
                            Tile.move(topPoint.x-Tile.width,topPoint.y);text.out="collision detected!";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(new Rectangle(Tile.x,Tile.y,Tile.width,Tile.height).contains(botPoint) && new Rectangle(Line.x,Line.y,Line.width,Line.height).contains(botPoint))
                        {
                            Tile.move(botPoint.x,botPoint.y-Tile.height);text.out="collision detected!";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }

       public Point intersection(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2,double x3, double y3, double x4, double y4)//I didn't write this. got it from http://www.ahristov.com/tutorial/geometry-games/intersection-lines.html (I altered it)
       {
            double d = (x1 - x2) * (y3 - y4) - (y1 - y2) * (x3 - x4);

            double xi = ((x3 - x4) * (x1 * y2 - y1 * x2) - (x1 - x2) * (x3 * y4 - y3 * x4)) / d;
            double yi = ((y3 - y4) * (x1 * y2 - y1 * x2) - (y1 - y2) * (x3 * y4 - y3 * x4)) / d;

            int x=(int)Math.round(xi);
            int y=(int)Math.round(yi);

            return new Point(x, y);
        }

//***************************************************************************************

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final collision Collision=new collision();
          Collision.run();
    }//end main
}//end class
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Java doesn't have an intersect function (really!?) you can do collision detection by simply comparying the X and Y, Width and Height values of the bounding boxes (rectangle) for each of the objects that could potentially collide.

So...  in the base object of each colliding object... i.e. if your player and enemy have a common base you can put a simple Rectangle object called something like BoundingBox.  If the common base is a built in Java class then you'll need to create a class that extends the build in class and have the player and enemy objects extend your new class or are instances of that class.

At creation (and each tick or update) you'll need to set the BoundingBox paremeters for both your player and enemy.  I don't have the Rectangle class infront of me but its most likely something like X, Y, Width and finally Height.  X and Y are that objects location in your game world.  The width and height are self explanatory I think.  They'll most likely come out from the right of the players location though so, if the X and Y were bothe at 0 and your Width and Height were both at 256 you wouldn't see anything because the character would be at the top left outside of the screen.

Anyways... to detect a collision, you'll want to compare the attributes of the player and enemy BoundingBoxes.  So something like this...

```
 if( Player.BoundingBox.X = Enemy.BoundingBox.X && If( Player.BoundingBox.Y = Enemy.BoundingBox.Y )
 {
      //Oh noes!  The enemy and player are on top of eachother.
 }
```

The logic can get sort of complicated but you'll need to compare the distances between each BoundingBox and compare locations.

Comment: Java does have an intersect method: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#intersects(java.awt.Rectangle) .

Comment: Argh, can't get the last ) to be included in the link. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a useful of an open source game that uses a lot of collisions: http://robocode.sourceforge.net/

You may take a look at the code and complement with the answers written here.

Answer (score 2):

is there a problem with:

```
Rectangle box1 = new Rectangle(100,100,100,100);
Rectangle box2 = new Rectangle(200,200,100,100);

// what this means is if any pixel in box2 enters (hits) box1
if (box1.contains(box2)) 
{
     // collision occurred
}

// your code for moving the boxes
```

this can also be applied to circles:

```
Ellipse2D.Double ball1 = new Ellipse2D.Double(100,100,200,200);
Ellipse2D.Double ball2 = new Ellipse2D.Double(400,100,200,200);

// what this means is if any pixel on the circumference in ball2 touches (hits)
// ball1
    if (ball1.contains(ball2)) 
    {
         // collision occurred
    }

    // your code for moving the balls
```

to check whether youve hit the edge of a screen you could use the following:

```
Rectangle screenBounds = jpanel.getBounds();
Ellipse2D.Double ball = new Ellipse2D.Double(100,100,200,200);  // diameter 200
Rectangle ballBounds = ball.getBounds();

if (!screenBounds.contains(ballBounds))
{
// the ball touched the edge of the screen
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a rectangle to surround each player and enemy, the height and width of the rectangles should correspond to the object you're surrounding, imagine it being in a box only big enough to fit it.

Now, you move these rectangles the same as you do the objects, so they have a 'bounding box'

I'm not sure if Java has this, but it might have a method on the rectangle object called .intersects() so you'd do if(rectangle1.intersectS(rectangle2) to check to see if an object has collided with another.

Otherwise you can get the x and y co-ordinates of the boxes and using the height/width of them detect whether they've intersected yourself.

Anyway, you can use that to either do an event on intersection (make one explode, or whatever) or prevent the movement from being drawn. (revert to previous co-ordinates)

edit: here we go

boolean

> intersects(Rectangle r) 
>             Determines whether or not this Rectangle and the specified
>   Rectangle intersect.

So I would do (and don't paste this code, it most likely won't work, not done java for a long time and I didn't do graphics when I did use it.)

```
Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);

Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(enemy.x, enemy.y, enemy.width, enemy.height);

//detects when the two rectangles hit
if(rect1.intersects(rect2))
{

System.out.println("game over, g");
}
```

obviously you'd need to fit that in somewhere.

Comment: This is what I was getting at. Java does have intersect, but I am struggling to apply it to the code I already have. Would I have to define the rectangle inside player() and enemy()?

Comment: No.. I've not used the painting stuff in java before, but you should definately have an object like "Creature", and then create instances of Creature i.e. player/enemy or make them subclasses which you create instances of. Create object should contain all that's needed for an Update/Draw NoCharsLeft

Answer (score 1):

No need to use rectangles ... compare the coordinates of  2 players constantly.

like 
`if(x1===x&&y1==y)` 
**remember to increase the range of x when ur comparing.**

if ur rectangle width is 30 take as `if (x1>x&&x2>x+30)`..likewise y

Answer (score 0):

First create classes Player and Entity

```
public class Entity {

    int x, y, width, height;

    public Entity(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        this.width=width;
        this.height=height;
    }
}

public class Player {

    int x, y, width, height;

    public Player(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        this.width=width;
        this.height=height;
    }
}
```

Next add this classes to Main class, and add method:

```
public static boolean collision (Player player, Entity entity) {
    return player.x+player.width>=entity.x&&player.x<=entity.x+entity.width&&player.y<=entity.y+entity.height&&player.y+player.height>=entity.y;
}
```

Main class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Main extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }
    Player player = new Player(100,100,50,50);
    Entity entity = new Entity(75,75,50,50);
    Timer timer = new Timer(16,this);
    public Main(){
        setSize(500,500);
        setVisible(true);

        timer.start();
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        repaint();
        if (collision(player,entity)){
             //collision action
        }
    }
    public void paint (Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawImage(playerImage,player.x,player.y,player.width,player.height,null);
        g.drawImage(entityImage,entity.x,entity.y,entity.width,entity.height,null);
    }
    public static boolean collision (Player player, Entity entity) {
        return player.x+player.width>=entity.x&&player.x<=entity.x+entity.width&&player.y<=entity.y+entity.height&&player.y+player.height>=entity.y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I reasently coded my own framework and this collision was very important. I think i made it very simple. It works with scale and the BufferedImage Method getRGB(x,y).

```
public boolean collidesWith(Sprite object) {

    if (new Rectangle(x,y,(int)(width*getScale()),(int)(height*getScale()))
            .intersects(new Rectangle(object.x,object.y,(int)(object.width * object.getScale()),
                    (int)(object.height * object.getScale())))){

        //making the first mask to compare that one with the other one
        long[][][] maskThis = new long[(int)(width * getScale())][(int)(height*getScale())][3];

        for (int widthThis = 0; widthThis < this.width * getScale(); widthThis++){
            for (int heightThis = 0; heightThis < this.height * getScale(); heightThis++){

                maskThis[widthThis][heightThis][0] =
                        image.getRGB((int)(widthThis/this.getScale()),(int)(heightThis/this.getScale()));
                maskThis[widthThis][heightThis][1] = widthThis+1+x;
                maskThis[widthThis][heightThis][2] = heightThis+1+y;
            }
        }


        //making the second mask to compare that one with the other one
        long[][][] maskObject = new long[(int)(object.width* object.getScale())][(int)(object.height* object.getScale())][3];

        for (int widthThis = 0; widthThis < object.width * object.getScale(); widthThis++){
            for (int heightThis = 0; heightThis < object.height * object.getScale(); heightThis++){

                maskObject[widthThis][heightThis][0] =
                        object.getImage().getRGB((int)(widthThis/object.getScale()),(int)(heightThis/object.getScale()));
                maskObject[widthThis][heightThis][1] = widthThis+1+ object.x;
                maskObject[widthThis][heightThis][2] = heightThis+1 + object.y;
            }
        }

        //the final answer
        for (int thatWidth = 0; thatWidth < this.width * getScale(); thatWidth++) {
            for (int thatHeight = 0; thatHeight < this.height * getScale(); thatHeight++) {

                if (maskThis[thatWidth][thatHeight][0] != 0) {
                    for (int objectThatWidth = 0; objectThatWidth < object.width * object.getScale(); objectThatWidth++){
                        for (int objectThatHeight = 0; objectThatHeight < object.height * object.getScale(); objectThatHeight++) {
                            if (maskObject[objectThatWidth][objectThatHeight][1] == maskThis[thatWidth][thatHeight][1]
                                    && maskObject[objectThatWidth][objectThatHeight][2] == maskThis[thatWidth][thatHeight][2]
                                    && maskObject[objectThatWidth][objectThatHeight][0] != 0
                            ){
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: There is a small Mistake i made sorry for that but the code is useful anyway

Comment: I think there is a problem with my Mirroring Method because width and heigth get negativ if i mirror it, but the negativ coordinates are only negativ in the drawing so the attributes x & y are constant on the same position, but there are wrong.

Comment: If you are saying that the code in your answer contains bugs, then you should fix the code. I don't think posting an answer with code that does not work is helpful. You are allowed to edit your answer.

Answer (score -1):

It's Java code for collision of two or more ImageViews not rectangles or other,use ImageViews Instead.

1.This code of Collision works every where in any views or layouts.

2.Add a timer to repeat it and to detect collision repeatedly.

3.It only works with views and layout.

```
if ((getLocationX(_v1) > (getLocationX(_v2) - ((_w2*3) + 40))) && (getLocationX(_v1) < (getLocationX(_v2) + ((_w2*3) +40)))){

if ((getLocationY(_v1) > (getLocationY(_v2) - ((_h2*3) + 40))) && (getLocationY(_v1) < (getLocationY(_v2) + ((_h2*3) +40)))){

 showMessage("Collided");

}

}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't provide any useful question, compared to the other answers on this question. Could you update your answer to clarify? Also, unless I'm missing something, your `if`-statements are identical.

Comment: AoA! What you want to say sir sorry didn't get it.How my    if    statement is identical.