# How to Find that moving image is overlapping the stationary image?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

i am working on a project in which i have to move one image and there are two more images, and on the overlapping of these stationary images, i have to perform a task. middle image is movable and other to images are stationary(Like we have in Lock Screens).

I am done with the moving part, but i am having trouble to overlapping the images. I am not getting that how we will find that when moving image is overlapping the stationary one.

Do anyone have any suggestions for this query???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this response to a similar but not identical question might help!

[Collision Detection between two images in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335600/collision-detection-between-two-images-in-java)

**Edit**

An example of this might be (I don't really do much Android dev, so excuse me if this doesn't work):

Override `onWindowFocusChanged(boolean focus)` with something like this.

```
import android.graphics.Rect;

imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

Rect rect1 = new Rect();
imageView1.getDrawingRect(rect1);

Rect rect2 = new Rect();
imageView2.getDrawingRect(rect2);

if (Rect.intersects(rect1, rect2) {
   //intersected
}
```

Comment: thank you for answer. But, i am not getting that how we can implement that on imageview??

Comment: See the edit for a very rough example. I'm not really an Android developer.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the x, y, width and hegiht values of the pictures and compare. Think in the window like a grid where the 4 vertexes of an picture are x, y, width and height values and compare it.