# Detecting if a 2D Graphics fill Rect is in another fillRect(eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse

```
private JPanel contentPane;
private KeyListener myKeyListener;
JLabel lblUp;
JLabel lblMiddle;
JLabel lblDown;
JButton btnStart;
JLabel lblScore;
int lblu = 0;
int x = 0;
int y = 50;
int u = 1;
int w = 1;
int rxx = 0;
int ryy = 0;
int s = 0;

Timer timer;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Game_1 frame = new Game_1();
                frame.setVisible(true);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */

public Game_1() {

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblScore = new JLabel("0");
    lblScore.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lblScore.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    lblScore.setBounds(388, 0, 46, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblScore);

    addKeyListener(this);

}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
    Graphics pen = this.contentPane.getGraphics();
    int maxh = contentPane.getHeight();
    int maxw = contentPane.getWidth();

    if(y < 0){
        y = maxh -50;
    }
    if(y > maxh-45){
        y = 0;
    }

    if (arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        if(u ==0){
        pen.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        pen.fillRect(0, 0, maxw, maxh);

        y = y - 10;
        pen.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        pen.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50);
        pen.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        pen.fillRect(x - 50, y, 50, 50);
        x = x + 1;
        if (x >= maxw) {

            pen.fillRect(x - 30, y, 50, 50);
            x = 0;
        }
        }
    } else if (arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        if(u ==1){
            pen.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            pen.fillRect(0, 0, maxw, maxh);

            pen.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            pen.fillRect(0, 0, maxw, maxh);

            Timer timer = new Timer(100, this);
            timer.start();
            u = 0;

        }else if(u ==0){
            x = x +10;

        }
    } else if (arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        if(u ==0){
        pen.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        pen.fillRect(0, 0, maxw, maxh);



        pen.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        y = y+ 10;
        if (x >= maxw) {

            pen.fillRect(x - 30, y, 50, 50);
            x = 0;
        }
        }

    }  else if (arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        if(u ==0){
        pen.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        pen.fillRect(0, 0, maxw, maxh);



        pen.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        x = x- 10;
        if (x < 0) {

            pen.fillRect(x - 30, y, 50, 50);
            x = maxw;
        }
        }

    }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {

}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {

}

public void run() {

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    Graphics pen = this.contentPane.getGraphics();
    int maxh = contentPane.getHeight();
    int maxw = contentPane.getWidth();
    pen.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    pen.fillRect(0, 0, maxw, maxh);

    pen.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    pen.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50);
    pen.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    pen.fillRect(x - 50, y, 50, 50);
    x = x + 1;
    if (x >= maxw) {

        pen.fillRect(x - 30, y, 50, 50);
        x = 0;

    }
    if(w ==1){
        Random r = new Random();

        int ry = r.nextInt(maxh - 0) + 100;

        int rx = r.nextInt(maxw - 0) + 100;
        rxx = rx;
        ryy = ry;
        pen.setColor(Color.RED);
        pen.fillRect(rx, ry, 10, 10);
        w = 0;
    }
    pen.setColor(Color.RED);
    pen.fillRect(rxx, ryy, 10, 10);

if(x-50 <= rxx && x > rxx && y > ryy && y-50 <= ryy){
s ++;
System.out.println("PUNKT");
pen.setColor(Color.BLACK);
pen.fillRect(rxx, ryy, 10, 10);
w = 1;
}

}
}
```

> here is the Problem: it only detects that they touch in the left top >corner(the wrong code is at the end, the last if)
>   you can start the game by pressing the Right arrow Button on you're Keyboard.Moving upwards: up Key on you're Keyboard.Moving downwards:down Key on your're Keyboard.The right Button also lets you move to the right, the left Button to the left.[Picture of the Game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iF7HV.png)

Comment: I want, that the Rect detects that it touches the other in every part of it, not only in the left top corner

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/335600/collision-detection-between-two-images-in-java

Comment: nope isnt the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally fixed it. For those who are interested, here is the fixed part of the code:

```
if (x+d >= x2 && x <= x2 && y+d >=y2 && y <= y2) {
s++;
d = d + s*10;
System.out.println("PUNKT");
pen.setColor(Color.BLACK);
pen.fillRect(x2, y2, 10, 10);
w = 1;
if (s == 10) {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Achievement get: " + s + "Punkte!");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want, that the Rect detects that it touches the other in every part
>   of it, not only in the left top corner

Let's assume you've got first rect with: `x1, y1, width1, height1` and second rect with `x2, y2, width2, height2`. The first rect touched the second in every part of it (so the second one is contained in the first one) when `x1 <= x2 && x2+width2 <= x1+width2 && y1 <= y2 && y2+height <= y1+height` 
so

```
if (x1 <= x2 && x2+width2 <= x1+width2 && y1 <= y2 && y2+height <= y1+height) {
    // the second rect is contained in the first rect
}
```

Comment: also only detects in the left top corner